# Spring Boot - How would I implement Web sockets to make a simple chatting system?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I'm trying to make a website that basically has a chat system where anyone can connect to and chat with each other, there is a registration process and login process that I have already implemented connected to a DB, now the biggest and most confusing part is implementing the chat feature.

**I am using JSP for the view and vanilla javascript**

I have tried tutorials but I can't seem to figure out ALOT of things

- Once the user logs into the website they should immediately be able to use the chat feature (which will show their name etc) , and if another user signs in, they should then be able to communicate to each other with the chat

(I honestly have no Idea simple or complex implementing this would be)

At the moment , from tutorials online.  I have these classes that sets up the WebSocket.

---

WebSocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/safespot").withSockJS();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

---

ChatController.java

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat.register")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public MessageModel register(@Payload MessageModel message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", message.getSender());
        return message;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.send")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public MessageModel sendMessage(@Payload MessageModel message) {
        return message;
    }

}
```

---

MessageModel.java

```
public class MessageModel {

    private String content;
    private String sender;
    private MessageType type;
    
    public enum MessageType {
        CHAT,LEAVE,JOIN
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public MessageType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(MessageType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    
}
```

---

The jsp for the chat box itself

```
        <div id="chat-page">
            <div class="chat-container">
            
                <!-- Header of the chat Box -->
                <div class="chat-header">
                  <h1 class="chat-heading mb-1">Welcome</h1>
                  <p class="chat-para mb-1">Please be respectful in the chat</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="connecting">Connecting...</div>

                <!-- This is where the chat output will appear -->
                <ul id="messageArea">
                    
                </ul>
                
                <!-- Input box -->
                <form id="messageForm" name="messageForm" nameForm="messageForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group clearfix">
                            <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type a message..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control" 
                                style="border-radius: 0; color: #fff" />
                            <button type="button" class="chat-send-btn">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Some pictures of what the UI looks like

[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpCJQ.png)

[The chat box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMzT4.png)

---- I know this is very vague but if anyone can please guide my on how to get close to doing this, I'd appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `TCP` socket. Conduct the necessary WS handshakes then from there websocket frames are just TCP packets.

Potential digression:
I have built something similar in a c++ webserver using websockets for a realtime public chat where all users have a unique identity and can use the chat immediately upon loading. It has no login system implemented but it does have a database where it stores all messages from users recording username and time. The results in using c++ embedded webserver and embedded SQL solution with websockets for a web chat were rather neat. with a c++ back end monitoring sockets and a web front end enabled me to ensure user activity and connection state were all processed quickly to provide a smooth realtime chat environment.

The chat is online at: https://1338th.com

If this is of any interest to you in solving your own issues let me know.

Comment: ,I'll look into that thanks, so implementing this feature wouldn't be hard right?